# Cannot build my class library on Release, only on Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, release

I've right clicked the project in Visual Studio and selected properties. Then I changed the Build configuration to Release. But even after hitting `Control+Shift+B` to build my library, I still find the /Release/ folder empty.

[image]

If I close the properties window and re open it, I see the option has switched back to `Active(debug)`

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't shown the bottom bit of the screen where it shows where it's going to build to.

Comment: Is this the only project in the solution, did you check the configuration manager? Does it successfully build in Debug?

Comment: @msarchet: The solution has another project, a Console application which is the startup. Maybe that is the issue? Advice?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't actually changed to make the Release configuration active - you've just gone to the properties for the Release configuration.

The "active configuration" is normally in a toolbar just under the main menu - look for "Debug" there and change it to "Release" like this:

[image]

Or go to "Build > Configuration Manager" and change the active release there.

[image]

Comment: Build > Configuration Manager is the ticket.

Comment: That solved it. What do the properties actually **do** then, if they don't get saved and just rollback?

Comment: @n8wrl: Now that is just handy. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Sergio: It's not that the properties themselves don't get saved - but you were just changing *which version of the properties you were viewing*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your Output Window of Visual Studio and after successful build ensure that your project's DLL is created in Release folder, with actual complete path provided, **where you are checking for binary presence**.
2. If it's ok, check if your Console application doesn't have any post build event in it, which simply moves the binaries of DLL projects.
3. If it's not, try to not use Control+Shift+B combination, but simply make a RightCLick DLL project and make it **Rebuild**.

Hope this helps.